# Why is Euler's reasoning correct in his proof that $\sum_n n^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, math-history

I was reading Euler's proof that $\sum_n n^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and I don't agree with his reasoning. My issue is outlined below.

---

First, Euler observed that the function $\sin x$ has roots at $x = 0, ±π, ±2π, ±3π, \ldots$. Next, he observed that the infinite product $x(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{(2\pi)^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{(3\pi)^2})\ldots$ also has roots at $x = 0, ±π, ±2π, ±3π, \ldots$.

*Euler then believed that these two functions are equivalent*.

I have a problem with the above statement. Obviously, having the same roots does not imply that the two functions are equivalent. For instance, $f(x)=0$ also has roots at $x = 0, ±π, ±2π, ±3π, \ldots$.

Euler then goes on to use the infinite product and Maclaurin expansion of $\sin x$ to compare coefficients of $x^3$. But his *belief* that those two functions are equivalent stains all subsequent parts of the proof.

Am I missing something obvious here? Or was Euler not rigourous enough in his proof?

Comment: By modern standards, Euler's argument is not rigorous.

Comment: If you study complex analysis, then you can understand that all "entire functions" (possibly of finite order) that have zeros precisely at given points can be expressed by infinite product with some varying factors.

Comment: Except for $f(x)=0$, it is enticing to assume that two functions sharing the same roots exactly are the same since a function can be expressed by its roots, $f(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)....=g(x)$ , should lead to f(x)=g(x) as long as not one of the functions have more roots than the other.

Comment: I discuss this issue in section 5 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view). The point is that both $\text{sinc}(x)$ and $\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$ are entire functions with simple roots at the elements of $\pi\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ (and only there), hence Euler's argument is perfectly rigorous once a corollary of the Mittag-Leffler theorem is invoked, namely that the Weierstrass product of the sine function has no exponential part.

Comment: On the other hand Euler produced *many* proofs of the identity $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$, probably since he was aware of the "leap of faith" in his original proof.

Comment: @Nochance I disagree, as $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=2x$ both have the same set of roots yet are not the same function

Comment: @Jack Thank you! I will have a look at your notes

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Those notes are amazing! I can't even imagine the work you put into that (content-wise and Latex-wise). Have you considered publishing it as a book?

Comment: @Klangen, you are correct but f(x)=x can't be written in the form (x-r1)(x-r2).... I  still stick to my suggestion :)

Comment: @NoChance Take $r_1=0$. Then $f(x)=(x-r_1)$ and $g(x)=(x-r_1)$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example involving the null function makes no sense. Euler did not just claim that all the zeros of the sine function are also zeros of$$x\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{(2\pi)^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{(3\pi)^2}\right)\ldots;\tag1$$he claimed also that both functions have the same set of zeros.

But, yes, is argument is no rigorous by modern standars. How did he know that the sine function had no other (complex non-real) zeros besides those from $\pi\mathbb Z$? I suppose that that's way he extended the sine function to $\mathbb C$ (and, no, there are no more zeros).

And of course, even assuming that, one still has to do something else to justify the equality $\sin x=(1)$.

---

You will find [here](https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf) a list of proofs of that equality, compiled by our former moderator Robin Chapman.

Comment: Thank you for the remarks and the link. But then the function $x(x²-\pi²)(x²-(2\pi)²)(x²-(3\pi)²)$ also has the same set of zeros as the product above as well as the sine function, yet is far from being equivalent to them...

Comment: If you are talking about the infinite product, then that product is not a function from $\mathbb C$ into itself, since the product almost never converges. The product defined by Euler, on the other hand, converges for each $x\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: Oh OK I understand. So the requirement for two functions to be considered "equivalent" is that both converge on the same domains (in this case $\mathbb{C}$) and that they both have the same set of roots?

Comment: Yes. Well, more or less. What we actually want is that they're the *same* function.